# How to override the Process button in the Process order screen in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

How to override the Process button in the Process order screen in Acumatica
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04TuO.png)

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way to directly the "Process" function for a specific processing screen but I am unaware of it nor do I see anything obvious in the customizer to do so. You could try to override a method within the Sales Order graph that you know fires within this process and implement your custom logic there. This way it would be hit by both the processing page and whatever action item you override within the order directly.